CVE-2023-36049 System.Net.Requests net6.0
I use syft and grype to find vulnerabilities "CRITICAL and HIGH" in my "net6.0" solution.
Grype found the vulnerability CVE-2023-36049
https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c3hf-8vgx-72rh


CVE-2023-36049 indicates that the package System.Net.Requests have the problem.
And the solution is to install SDK 6.0.317 or runtime 6.0.25

I used the command

dotnet list package --include-transitive

to find the System.Net.Requests, but the package doesn't appear
I used the DependencyVisualizerTool to find System.Net.Requests, but the package doesn't appear
SDKs installed in my machine
.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.818 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.426 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.317 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.423 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  8.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  8.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Runtimes
.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.32 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.22 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.31 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Why does grype indicate this package if I don't use it explicitly?
How solve this vulnerability?
Why in the autogenerated file *deps.json find?
"System.Net.Requests": "6.0.0.0",

"System.Net.Requests/6.0.0.0": {
        "compile": {
          "System.Net.Requests.dll": {}
        },
        "compileOnly": true
      },
"System.Net.Requests/6.0.0.0": {
      "type": "referenceassembly",
      "serviceable": false,
      "sha512": ""
    },

Thanks,
UPDATE 20240620:
In csproj add
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Requests" Version="4.3.0" ExcludeAssets="all"/>

And syft detect this packages

And grype didn't detect vulnerability in System.Net.Requests
I dont understand the difference of System.Net.Requests package and netcore System.Net.Requests system dll
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Requests

maybe it's not listed because it's part of the runtime under dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.xxx?

@tinmanjk yes, but how to use the newest version of net 6 sdk?, I add global.json with "version": "6.0.423" but in dep.json indicates 6.0.0.
